# Duplicate Json in Spring Boot Response

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a RestController class with a method that returns duplicate json. Weird thing is when I pass a string to the response object. The Json is okay. However when I pass any other object, be it a list, hashmap etc. I get the json duplicated. Am checking the response in PostMan.

Sample Code sending correct response with string.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> test() {
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok().
                body("My test string");
    }
```

Output
[image]

Code sending duplicate Json with HashMap or any Model

```
@RequestMapping(value = "test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> test() {
        HashMap<String, Object> fullObject = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok().
                body(fullObject);
    }
```

The response I get

[image]

Here is my security config where I pass a few filters during authentication.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtConfig jwtConfig;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final ApplicationUserService applicationUserService;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationSecurityConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, ApplicationUserService applicationUserService, JwtConfig jwtConfig) {
        this.applicationUserService = applicationUserService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.jwtConfig = jwtConfig;
    }


    //JWT AUTHENTICATION
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(),jwtConfig))
                .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenVerifier(jwtConfig), JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "index", "/css/*", "/js/*", "/h2/**","/login", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/token/refresh").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole(STUDENT.name())
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/management/api/**").hasAuthority(COURSE_WRITE.getPermission())
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/management/api/**").hasAuthority(COURSE_WRITE.getPermission())
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/management/api/**").hasAuthority(COURSE_WRITE.getPermission())
                .antMatchers("/management/api/**").hasAnyRole(ADMIN.name(), ADMINTRAINEE.name())
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }


    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(applicationUserService);
        return provider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }


}
```

My JWTTokenVerifier

```
public class JwtTokenVerifier extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtConfig jwtConfig;

    public JwtTokenVerifier(JwtConfig jwtConfig) {
        this.jwtConfig = jwtConfig;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        if (request.getServletPath().equals("/login") || request.getServletPath().equals("/token/refresh")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(jwtConfig.getAuthorizationHeader());

        if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(authorizationHeader) || !authorizationHeader.startsWith(jwtConfig.getTokenPrefix())) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        String token = authorizationHeader.replace(jwtConfig.getTokenPrefix(), "");


        try {

            Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret".getBytes());
            JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm).build();
            DecodedJWT decodedJWT = verifier.verify(token);

            String username = decodedJWT.getSubject();
            String[] roles = decodedJWT.getClaim("authorities").asArray(String.class);
            Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
            stream(roles).forEach(role -> {
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
            });

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Token %s cannot be trusted", token));
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    }


}
```

My JWTUsernameandpassword

```
public class JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final JwtConfig jwtConfig;

    public JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                                                      JwtConfig jwtConfig) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.jwtConfig = jwtConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {

        try {
            UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(request.getInputStream(), UsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationRequest.class);

            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    authenticationRequest.getUsername(),
                    authenticationRequest.getPassword()
            );

            Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
            return authenticate;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

       /* String access_token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(authResult.getName())
                .claim("authorities", authResult.getAuthorities())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().plusDays(jwtConfig.getTokenExpirationAfterDays())))
                .signWith(secretKey)
                .compact();

        String refresh_token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(authResult.getName())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().plusDays(jwtConfig.getRefreshTokenExpirationAfterDays())))
                .signWith(secretKey)
                .compact();*/

        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret".getBytes());
        String access_token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(authResult.getName())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10 * 6000 * 1000))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                .withClaim("authorities", authResult.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .sign(algorithm);

        String refresh_token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(authResult.getName())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 30 * 60 * 1000))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                .sign(algorithm);

//        response.addHeader(jwtConfig.getAuthorizationHeader(), jwtConfig.getTokenPrefix() + access_token);
//        response.setHeader("jwt_access", jwtConfig.getTokenPrefix() + access_token);
//        response.setHeader("jwt_refresh", jwtConfig.getTokenPrefix() + refresh_token);

        Map<String, String> tokens = new HashMap<>();
        tokens.put("access_token", jwtConfig.getTokenPrefix() + access_token);
        tokens.put("refresh_token", refresh_token);
        response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE); //"application/json"
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), tokens);

    }
}
```

Comment: I copied your code to a new Spring boot project, but I can't reproduce this. Do you have some interceptors/filters running that might cause the duplication?

Comment: @g00glen00b I have edited my answer with the filters I pass

Comment: The `{}{}` json result you got would be an invalid value. Seems to be more like a visual bug.
Have you verified that CLI GET-requests or requesting the API on a browser is getting the same result? And what is the answer if you add some data to the response map called` fullObject`? Still redundant json shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `JwtTokenVerifier` you call `filterChain.doFilter(request, response)` multiple times. For example, you call it both in the try/catch and outside:

```java
try {
    // ...
    // Called here
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Token %s cannot be trusted", token));
}

// And here
filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
```

The solution is to refactor your code so that it's only calling the `filterChain.doFilter(request, response)` statement once.

P.S. You also call `filterChain.doFilter(request, response)` in the if-statements at the top of your logic. So for the `/login` or `/token/refresh` endpoint, the response might be tripled.